# SQL Server forcing nvarchar to be converted to int on inserting data in a composite clustered primary key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I created a composite primary key using the fluent API for EF Core, which created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Review]  
(
    [UserId]           NVARCHAR(450) NOT NULL,
    [ArticleId]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [ReviewRating]     FLOAT(53)     NOT NULL,
    [ReviewContent]    NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [ReviewLastUpdate] DATETIME2(7)  NULL,
    [ReviewCreated]    DATETIME2(7)  DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [ReviewVisible]    BIT           DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Review] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [ArticleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Review_AspNetUsers_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Review_Article_ArticleId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ArticleId]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Article] ([ArticleId]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The `UserId` is from the AspNetUsers table while the Article is a custom table setup by me that auto-generates it's id.

The scaffolded Create Page had a drop down which I replaced with a hidden text-box, that stores the value of UserId of the user that is currently logged in and submits it when the form is submitted.

But on submit, I am thrown a SQL exception

> SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '57ed59a3-e2c9-4805-a57d-3d1ea7afed3f' to data type int.

The `57ed59a3-e2c9-4805-a57d-3d1ea7afed3f` is the `UserId`. Even when I try to directly enter a value, the same error is thrown to me.

I even tried changing it to nonclustered as it might be conflicting due to 3rd reason stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017#Restrictions

But it didn't make a difference. Can anyone point me in a direction of what I can do to solve this error?

Comment: SQL Server does what your code tells it to do. You're trying to store a GUID string into an *integer field*, which is impossible. Fix your code or the field type. The error is pretty clear

Comment: `Even when I try to directly enter a value` this will still fail because the data is still wrong. If you want to use a GUID in a key (which is a pretty bad idea itself), change the field type to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`

Comment: Did you inspect the UserID value coming across during submit and can you guarantee that UserID  is going out to be saved the way you think? Perhaps you have mixed up the two fields in translation.

Comment: As for why using a GUID is a bad idea, it will result in index fragmentation unless it's generated by a sequential GUID algorithm.

Comment: Even if you've swapped the UserID and ArticleID values in your code, the field that accepts a GUID should have the *correct* type - UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. A GUID is 16 bytes long but its string representation would take 36 characters. Saved as nvarchar, they'd take 72 bytes. The index will take 4 times more space compared to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Comment: @RossBush I checked upto `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` till where it was in string format.

Comment: As to why the UserId is nvarchar(450), it's a FK from AspNetUsers, which .net core auto generated from IdentityUser when I added authentication to my project. Haven't messed with that yet. I am not trying to store a GUID String into an integer field lol, that would be dumb.

Comment: So if you realize that you can't store a GUID string in an integer field, your question should be "why is my code using a GUID string when I think it should be using an integer?".   And since you haven't shown us the code that does that, there's no way we can help.

Comment: What do you expect will happen?  You are attempting to insert guid into int column.